# Safe way to parameterize substring query with AND operator in MySQL + Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to safely build an SQL query from a given string. The string can contain whitespaces.

```
string = "chair"

query = """SELECT *
             FROM albums
             WHERE title LIKE %s"""
values = ('%' + string + '%',)
cur.execute(query,values)
# >> SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title LIKE '%chair%'
```

But I can't figure out how to safely extend this to search for multiple words with the AND operator.

```
string = "big blue chair"
# >> SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title LIKE '%big%' AND
#                               title LIKE '%blue%' AND
#                               title LIKE '%chair%'
```

(I know this is what FULLTEXT searches are for, etc ... but this is for a very small dataset and is fast enough.)

Comment: What's unsafe about doing the obvious: `values = ["%{}%".format(val) for val in string.split()]`? Not being snarky, I'm just not sure what your concern is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dynamically expand both the `query` and `values` based on `string`, you can do it like this:

```
string = "big blue chair"
query = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title LIKE %s"
values = ["%{}%".format(val) for val in string.split()]
for _ in values[1:]:  # iterate over len(values) - 1
    query += " AND title LIKE %s"
print(query)
print(values)
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title LIKE %s AND title LIKE %s AND title LIKE %s
['%big%', '%blue%', '%chair%']
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your string on spaces.

Then:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title LIKE %s AND title LIKE %s AND title LIKE %s", (var1 , var2, var3))
```